# PHP Search Form using mysql database

Tags: php

I have looked on threads of the same nature and feel don't offer what looking for.

I want to create a search form using two fields "Categories" and "Province", have table

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo -> prepare("select * from kyaami_users where services LIKE '%$search%' OR province LIKE '%$search%' LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query -> bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query -> execute();
```

The problem with the above code is that it returns all the fields on the table, how can i make it to return only the user selected fields

Comment: Paste the code here, not the link or image

Comment: $search=$_POST['search'];
$query = $pdo->prepare("select * from kyaami_users where services LIKE '%$search%' OR province LIKE '%$search%'  LIMIT 0 , 10");
$query->bindValue(1, "%$search%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query->execute();

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM kyaami_users WHERE services LIKE :services OR province LIKE :province LIMIT 0, 10");
$query->execute(array(':services' => 1, ':province' => 1));
```